# Programs opening slow when DNS servers set

Tags: windows-7, dns

So we have a computer (win 7) which on purpose is not allowed connections to the outside world. It still has our internal DNS-Servers set to be able to reach internal servers/fileshares and so on.

For a long time it has been completely disconnected from the network, even internal and all was good. Now that we have it connected to the network (only internal connections allowed), we notice, that opening programs takes very long. For example, about 20 seconds for notepad++.

When pulling out the network cable it opens in a split second.

The machine has been connected to the network for a few days now (windows updates all came through our local WSUS server) so it shouldn't be any update ongoing which slows things down. Looking at task manager, CPU and HDD load are either 0% or only a low number.

I noticed, that when I remove the DNS servers (local servers) the programs are starting fast again!

What could be the reason for this? We would obviously like to have the DNS servers set. Currently we're using a workaround to put the most important servers in the host file, but this can only be a temporary solution.

Comment: What DNS queries is it making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the proxy on the server and allowing the machine to reach the proxy in the DMZ. It was working normal again.

Still strange though, especially that it's trying to reach some addresses from here every second knowledge.digicert.com/generalinformation/INFO4629.html

Answer (score 0):

It’s very hard to say without any logs but I’m going to assume some things and make a guess.
Im going to assume your DNS server is part of a Domain and you have a PKI setup. I’m also going to assume that each device on the network’s traffic is encrypted.

Any time a program is opened it calls to the internet to check for updates and licensing etc.. I’m going to take a leap and say the encryption standards or certificates (from the PKI) that the device is using is from an older set or CPU intensive in someway to slow down traffic from the DNS server. Or something to that effect.

So I would start by checking the IPSec Setting in the firewall for the PC and DNS server (maybe make an encryption on both sides and see if that fixes it).

Comment: I was assuming it would be updates as the computer in general isn't slow and programs without internet (explorer for example) open instantly. I wouldn't have thought about encryption being the cause. However the firewall on the machine is disabled, so I can't check IPSec settings. While I do have access to the DNS server, I'm not familiar enough with it to setup the encryption between them. Which logs would be interesting?

Comment: well lets start here is the computer joined to a domain. and does it take a long time to login and log off when connected to the network.

Comment: yes joined the same domain as the DNS servers, logging in/off is normal doesn't take any longer than usual. I believe only external connections are slow. Reaching the fileserver for example is also instant. External it'll get blocked at the firewall though

Comment: I can see tons of blocked connection attempts to an IP-address from this list: https://knowledge.digicert.com/generalinformation/INFO4629.html

pretty much ever 1-2 seconds (when the DNS servers are set)